# In Custom List View facing ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: android, arrays, listview

i want custome ListView with 2 textbox whene in First i can show number and in another i can show its missed call number , received or outgoing number,with date i am able to show date and call type in Secod Line of ListView but when i try to show number it gives following error .

```
04-30 16:38:02.764: E/AndroidRuntime(7312): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-30 16:38:02.764: E/AndroidRuntime(7312): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
04-30 16:38:02.764: E/AndroidRuntime(7312): at com.custom.ListViewAdapter.getView  (ListViewAdapter.java:64)
04-30 16:38:02.764: E/AndroidRuntime(7312):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2203)
04-30 16:38:02.764: E/AndroidRuntime(7312):     at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1204)
04-30 16:38:02.764: E/AndroidRuntime(7312):     at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1115)
04-30 16:38:02.764: E/AndroidRuntime(7312):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8339)
04-30 16:38:02.764: E/AndroidRuntime(7312):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
04-30 16:38:02.764: E/AndroidRuntime(7312):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1012)
04-30 16:38:02.764: E/AndroidRuntime(7312):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:381)
04-30 16:38:02.764: E/AndroidRuntime(7312):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:304)
04-30 16:38:02.764: E/AndroidRuntime(7312):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8339)
04-30 16:38:02.764: E/AndroidRuntime(7312):     at   android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
04-30 16:38:02.764: E/AndroidRuntime(7312):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
04-30 16:38:02.764: E/AndroidRuntime(7312):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8339)
04-30 16:38:02.764: E/AndroidRuntime(7312):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:526)
04-30 16:38:02.764: E/AndroidRuntime(7312):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:304)
04-30 16:38:02.764: E/AndroidRuntime(7312):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8339)
04-30 16:38:02.764: E/AndroidRuntime(7312):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
04-30 16:38:02.764: E/AndroidRuntime(7312):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
04-30 16:38:02.764: E/AndroidRuntime(7312):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8339)
04-30 16:38:02.764: E/AndroidRuntime(7312):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:801)
04-30 16:38:02.764: E/AndroidRuntime(7312):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1727)
04-30 16:38:02.764: E/AndroidRuntime(7312):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-30 16:38:02.764: E/AndroidRuntime(7312):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-30 16:38:02.764: E/AndroidRuntime(7312):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
04-30 16:38:02.764: E/AndroidRuntime(7312):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-30 16:38:02.764: E/AndroidRuntime(7312):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-30 16:38:02.764: E/AndroidRuntime(7312):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:870)
04-30 16:38:02.764: E/AndroidRuntime(7312):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:628)
04-30 16:38:02.764: E/AndroidRuntime(7312):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here , i have converted **List** to **String[]** but i am able to get output if i write
`lviewAdapter = new ListViewAdapter(this, timeArray, timeArray);` in which both prints **call Type** and **date**  but when i write
`lviewAdapter = new ListViewAdapter(this, timeArray, timeArray);` 
it Gives **ArrayIndexoutOfBoundException**

**ListView2Activity.java**

```
import java.sql.Date;
```

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.CallLog;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

public class ListView2Activity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener
{
 /** Called when the activity is first created. */

ListView lview;
ListViewAdapter lviewAdapter;
List<String> dir;
List<String> num;
String[] numArray ;
String[] timeArray;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main); 
    dir = new ArrayList<String>();
    num = new ArrayList<String>();
    Cursor managedCursor = managedQuery( CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,null, null,null, null);
    int number = managedCursor.getColumnIndex( CallLog.Calls.NUMBER ); 
    int type = managedCursor.getColumnIndex( CallLog.Calls.TYPE );
    int date = managedCursor.getColumnIndex( CallLog.Calls.DATE);

    Log.d("tag","call details");
    while ( managedCursor.moveToNext() ) 
    {
    String phNumber = managedCursor.getString( number );
    num.add(phNumber);

    String callType = managedCursor.getString( type );
    String callDate = managedCursor.getString( date );
    Date callDayTime = new Date(Long.valueOf(callDate));


    int dircode = Integer.parseInt( callType );
    switch( dircode )
    {
    case CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE:
        dir.add("OUTGOING" + " , "+ callDayTime);

        break;
    case CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE:
        dir.add("INCOMING"+ " , "+ callDayTime);


        break;
    case CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE:
        dir.add("MISSED"+  " , "+ callDayTime); 
        break;
    }// switch end
    Log.d("tag",phNumber +"," + dir );

    } // while end


     numArray = new String[num.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < num.size(); i++) 
    {
        numArray[i] = num.get(i);  
    //  Log.i("tag", "in array :" + num[i]);
    } // for end

     timeArray = new String[dir.size()];
    for (int j = 0; j < dir.size(); j++) {
        timeArray[j] = dir.get(j);  
    } // for end

    managedCursor.close();

    lview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView2);
    lviewAdapter = new ListViewAdapter(this, numArray, timeArray);

    System.out.println("adapter => "+lviewAdapter.getCount());

    lview.setAdapter(lviewAdapter);

    lview.setOnItemClickListener(this);
} // create end

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long id) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(this,"Title => "+numArray[position]+"=> n Description"+timeArray[position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}}
```

**ListViewAdapter.java**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
Activity context;
String title[];
String description[];

public ListViewAdapter(Activity context, String[] title, String[] description) {
    super();
    this.context = context;
    this.title = title;
    this.description = description;
}

public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return title.length;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

private class ViewHolder {
    TextView txtViewTitle;
    TextView txtViewDescription;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ViewHolder holder;
    LayoutInflater inflater =  context.getLayoutInflater();

    if (convertView == null)
    {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem_row, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.txtViewTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        holder.txtViewDescription = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.txtViewTitle.setText(title[position]);
    holder.txtViewDescription.setText(description[position]);

return convertView;
}
}
```

Comment: what is line 64 of ListViewAdapter.java?  I am guessing it is either  holder.txtViewTitle.setText(title[position]); or 
    holder.txtViewDescription.setText(description[position]);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The above code is working well i just copy and paste it and run this code and get the following result.

[image]

Comment: hey buddy it still gives me error in LG lu 3000 but in motorola atrix it working fine

Comment: I did not change single bit in your code just copy and paste and it works well just clean your project. Are you using something else too might be that will create problem.

Comment: no buddy cleaned many times but when i am using this code in motorola it working fine how ?

Comment: is it working in Motorola? I run this code on emulator not on any device. If it is not working on device I cant help you sorry.

Comment: ok buddy actaully i just run this code on Motorola atrix it run successfully but on LG lu 3000 it gives force close

Answer (score 0):

ok this is just a random guess, but I am thinking that one of your arrays is a different size.  This would cause the error you are seeing if return title.length > description.length.

Reasoning
ok when getCount() is called that is going to return how many views exist.  Lets assume that title.length = 5.  Now the ListView is going to want to generate the five views so will call getView for position =1...5.  If description.length = 3 for instance you would get an exception at getView() where position = 4 when calling

```
holder.txtViewDescription.setText(description[position]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lviewAdapter = new ListViewAdapter(this, numArray, timeArray);
System.out.println("adapter => "+lviewAdapter.getCount());
lview.setAdapter(lviewAdapter);
lview.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

replace above code

```
if(timeArray.length > 0 )
{
   lviewAdapter = new ListViewAdapter(this, numArray, timeArray);
   System.out.println("adapter => "+lviewAdapter.getCount());
   lview.setAdapter(lviewAdapter);
   lview.setOnItemClickListener(this);
}
```